# R if column name exists on a list add a prefix to the column name

Tags: r, list, dplyr, paste

I have found answers that help with part of this but I cannot get the full code working.

If a column name is on a vector list, then add a prefix

**Data:**

```
    data <-
    structure(list(ID = c(111L, 222L, 333L), 
    desc = c("uc1", "uc2", "uc3"),
    var1 = c("A", "A", "B"), 
    var2 = c("B", "B", "C"), 
    var3 = c("C", "C", "D"), 
    GENDER = c("F", "M", "M"), 
    AGE = c(25L, 25L, 24L)), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

    #list of demographic variables I need to add a prefix to for modelling   
    demog = c("GENDER", "AGE")
```

**What I would like to do:**

If a column name exists in my list of demographic variables then add a prefix "d" to the column name.

I have tried various versions along the lines of the below but none are working.

```
     #following creates errors    
         colnames(data)[demog[(demog %in% colnames(data))]] <-
          paste('d', colnames(data)[demog[(demog %in% colnames(data))]], sep = '_')

     data <- 
     ifelse(names(data) %in% demog, paste0(demog, 'd', sep = '_'), colnames(data))
```

I have a number of different lists for different groupings of variables so it cant be done manually. I would like an output where all other column names are the same but I have "d_GENDER" and "d_AGE".

Very grateful for any help.

Comment: a few was to do this but this will get it done: `demog = c("GENDER_d"="GENDER", "AGE_d"="AGE")

       data %>% dplyr::rename(any_of(demog))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rename_with`. This function accepts `tidy-select` statements to select which columns to transform. `any_off` is the one to be used here, as it accepts character vectors, and transforms only matching columns and ignores the remaining.

```
library(dplyr)

data |>
    rename_with(.cols = any_of(demog),
                .fn = ~paste0('d_',.x))
```

We can also adapt the OP's code to use base R (you were close):

```
colnames(data)[colnames(data) %in% demog] <- paste0("d_", colnames(data)[colnames(data) %in% demog])
```

Output

```
   ID desc var1 var2 var3 d_GENDER d_AGE
1 111  uc1    A    B    C        F    25
2 222  uc2    A    B    C        M    25
3 333  uc3    B    C    D        M    24
```

Comment: any_of() takes a character vector as its imput, as in the updated answer

Comment: Wow so simple! Thank you very much - I have never used |> before, must learn about this.

Comment: This is the (not so) new base pipe, as of R version >4.0. We can replace it with the dplyr pipe (`%>%`) in this case, as is. please be mindful of a few differences between the two pipes which may lead to problems in other analyses.

Comment: Included a base R answer